# Interaction Lagrangian with derivatives

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, perturbation-theory, interactions

I have a problem with derivatives in the interaction part of the Lagrangian.

Considering the Lagrangian
$${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\psi\partial^{\mu}\psi+
g\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\psi-\frac{m^2}{2}\psi^2-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi^2+\psi^2)^2$$

My question is: should I consider the term proportional to $g$ as a simple interaction carrying two extra $p$ in the vertex or things are more complex?

I seem to remember that there is a range of values of $g$ for which the lagrangian is a bona fide QFT but I cannot recall the argument.